# Cannot use Jupyter (IPython) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ipython, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I have Jupyter installed on my computer and have used it to run notebooks in my browser. Also, I have the Python plugin installed in VSCode. However, if I'm editing a Python file and I bring up the command palette and select `Jupyter: Run Selection/Line`, nothing happens, and I'm not shown a results window.

I'm on a Mac, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that I didn't have the folder containing the python file open in VS Code, and so I was running into permissions errors when VS Code tried to write Jupyter output.